# Configuring DNS on IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, iis, iis-7

I have a DNS name pointing to the server where my website is installed. If I ping `http://mydnsname`, I can see it pings the correct IP. But browsing this URL returns a 404 error. So do I have to do some setting on the server where my website is installed? I have very limited knowledge on DNS and IIS settings. So any help would be appreciated.

Windows Server : Windows Server 2008 Standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have default documents enabled for your site and  do indeed have a default document in your document root, then it may just be that you need to add a host name binding to your site.

1. Click on your site in IIS Manager
2. Under Edit Site in the right-hand pane click `Bindings...`
3. In the Site Bindings window click `Add...`
4. Set the Type, IP Address and Port as appropriate, then type `mydnsname` in the Host name box.
5. Click Ok, and Ok again.
6. Try hitting your site again.

It's also possible, if your server has more than one IP address, that your site is not bound to the same IP address that your dns name is resolving to.  In that case, check the bindings (same screen as the above steps) and make sure your site is listening (ie- has a binding) on that IP address.

Comment: @Appu Good deal :)  Glad it worked!

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more question. If I need `http://mydnsname` to point to a virtual directory inside the website, what should I do?

Comment: @Appu That, actually, is a completely different ball game and one I've not been willing to play yet.  There was actually a question asked yesterday about that.  http://serverfault.com/questions/241960/assigning-subdomain-to-a-subfolder-of-asp-net-application